# Uploading and downloading with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I made my localhost to upload files in Mongo DB with `server.js`

```js
//I have replaced my ID and PW
    const mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://myID:myPW@cluster0.0ct4j.mongodb.net/test";

// Mongo Connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () =>{
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo); // mongoose.mongo
    //gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Middleware
server.use(bodyParser.json()); 
server.use(methodOverride('_method'));  
// Mongo Connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  cache: true, // cache
  file: (req, file) => {
    return file.originalname + Date.now();
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

  server.get("/upload", (req,res) =>{
      res.render('upload');
  });

  // @desc uploads file to DB
  server.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/");
  });
```

And this is my `upload.ejs`

```js
<form action="/upload" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="custom-file mb-3">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

I can see these uploaded files in `localhost:3000/list` properly.

```js
<% if(files){ %>
  <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
    <div class="card card-body mb-3">
      <%= file.filename %>
      <a href= <%=mongoURI%> download=file>Download</a>
            <form action= "<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="get"> 
              <button class="delete">DELETE</button>
            </form>
            <form action="<%= file._id %>?_method=DOWNLOAD" method="get">
              <button class="download">DOWNLOAD</button>
            </form>

    </div>
    <% }) %>
      <% } else { %>
        <p>No files to show</p>
        <% } %>
```

`list.ejs` reads filenames in the right way, and I am trying to implement a downloading function as well as a deleting function, which I probably have to deal in `server.js` because the frontend should never interact directly with the database. I tried to borrow the logic from the uploading function, but didn't manage to.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the endpoints. Check the example project: https://github.com/kvnam/multer-gridfs-storage-demo/blob/master/app/controller.js.
The key part is:

```js
module.exports.getFile = (req, res) => {
  //Accepting user input directly is very insecure and should 
  //never be allowed in a production app. Sanitize the input.
  let fileName = req.body.text1;
  //Connect to the MongoDB client
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){

    if(err){
      return res.render('index', {title: 'Uploaded Error', message: 'MongoClient Connection error', error: err.errMsg});
    }
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    
    const collection = db.collection('test.files');
    const collectionChunks = db.collection('test.chunks');
    collection.find({filename: fileName}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      if(err){
        return res.render('index', {title: 'File error', message: 'Error finding file', error: err.errMsg});
      }
      if(!docs || docs.length === 0){
        return res.render('index', {title: 'Download Error', message: 'No file found'});
      }else{
        //Retrieving the chunks from the db
        collectionChunks.find({files_id : docs[0]._id}).sort({n: 1}).toArray(function(err, chunks){
          if(err){
            return res.render('index', {title: 'Download Error', message: 'Error retrieving chunks', error: err.errmsg});
          }
          if(!chunks || chunks.length === 0){
            //No data found
            return res.render('index', {title: 'Download Error', message: 'No data found'});
          }
          //Append Chunks
          let fileData = [];
          for(let i=0; i<chunks.length;i++){
            //This is in Binary JSON or BSON format, which is stored
            //in fileData array in base64 endocoded string format
            fileData.push(chunks[i].data.toString('base64'));
          }
          //Display the chunks using the data URI format
          let finalFile = 'data:' + docs[0].contentType + ';base64,' + fileData.join('');
          res.render('imageView', {title: 'Image File', message: 'Image loaded from MongoDB GridFS', imgurl: finalFile});
        });
      }
      
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I must say, the logic looks similar, but I am still struggling to implement this to my code. This shared git uses 'module' and '.pug' files that confuse me.

Comment: The 'pug' generates the UI. It has very good documentation but you do not have to use it. The 'module' export is related to NodeJs https://stackify.com/node-js-module-exports/.

Comment: Thank you, but I did get the logic putting together binaries in the server.js there. I just found out that MongoDB is different from Mongoose (what I am using). The example project is requiring MongoDB library.

Comment: Oh, I see! Is it necessary to use the Mongoose? It provides only connection, the other clients should work as well as described in https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-gridfs-storage